# Output text to page with a variable color and variable text

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create javascript function that has two parameters: text and color. In the code, I want to pass a color and some text. Then the code will write that in the correct color and text to the web page. Is this possible with only javascript or do I have to use css?

Comment: Welcome. Please read the rules and tips for asking questions. This is to broad and something that should not be hard to search answers to.

Comment: It's possible with just JS, you don't have to *write* CSS.

Comment: Probably better to go with CSS, JS has very limited set of styling the HTML.

Comment: @Teemu tell me about the rules you can not set via. JS? I thought anything could be manipulated via the dom.

Comment: @RonniSkansing Almost all ofcourse (pseudo-classes and elements are hard though), but then it will be manipulating of CSS ; ).

Comment: For what he's wanting to do, I wouldn't use CSS. It's one line of code in JS. `element.style.color = 'some color'`

Comment: @Teemu actully yea, great point with the psudo selectors, cause that would really mean digging into the stylesheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is set a color to some given text, this is easy. I'm not sure if I'm fully understanding what you want to do but from what I understand, here is a code snippet that will give you what you want:

```
function printIt(text, color) {
    var theEl = document.createElement("p");
    theEl.id = "el";
    var theText = document.createTextNode(text);
    theEl.style.color = color;
    document.body.appendChild(theEl);
    theEl.appendChild(theText);

}

printIt ("hello", "red");
```

When calling the `printIt()` function, you can pass to parameters: `text` and `color`. You can pass a hexidecimal color if you wanted to as well but this is the most straight forward answer that i can give with the information you provided.